# SQL query - What does taking the MIN of this boolean expression mean?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, boolean-expression

Excuse my ignorance about this... I'm taking a data analysis course and I stumbled upon this query in an exercise:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN MIN(REGEXP_CONTAINS(STRING(ActivityDate), DATE_REGEX)) = TRUE THEN
  "Valid"
  ELSE
    "Not Valid"
  END
    AS valid_test
  FROM
   `tracker_data_clean.daily-activity-clean`;
```

`ActivityDate` is a field that contains `date` type data and `DATE_REGEX` is a regular expression variable for a date format string.

What I don't know, is what does taking the `MIN()` of this boolean expression `REGEX_CONTAINS` do or mean.

I would appreciate if any of you could help me understand the concept of doing this.

Thanks !

Comment: I guess the question boils down to "what is the minimum of a boolean". Since booleans tend to be expressed as `0`(false) and `1`(true), the minimum would be `0`(false). This should be easy to check though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query selects rows from the table and applies the `REGEXP_CONTAINS()` function to every (string-converted) value in the `ActivityDate` column. `REGEXP_CONTAINS()` will either return `true` or `false` based on whether the value matches the regex pattern in `DATE_REGEX`.

How `MIN()` behaves here can vary by implementation:

- Booleans might be coerced as integers, so `MIN()` is evaluating `0`'s and `1`'s. If all the values are `1` (`true`), `MIN()` will be `1` (`true`), otherwise it will be `0` (`false`).
- Other implementations might evaluate booleans directly, so `MIN()` returns `true` if all of the values are `true`, because the minimum value is `true` (`true` being "greater" than `false`), otherwise it returns `false`.

The result, based on the implementation, is that `MIN()` returns `0`/`1`, or `false`/`true`. Either way, that result is compared to `true` in the `CASE` statement. If all values matched the regex, the comparison will be `true`.

Basically, the query is "does every row have a valid date in the `ActivityDate` column?" The result will be a table with a single column `valid_test` and one row, containing "Valid" if they all match, "Not Valid" otherwise.

Another way to look at it that would be relatable to some programming languages is that `MIN(bool_function())` is analogous to `all()`, meaning return `true` if all values are `true`. Similarly, `MAX(bool_function())` would be analogous to `any()`, meaning return `true` if any value is `true`.

Comment: That was a really good explanation, now that I get the point of the MIN() it seems kind of obvious. Thank you very much !